# Crash when opening Option Menu

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have ordinary activity with Option Menu, which I created by this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  menu.add(0, 1, 0, "A");
  menu.add(0, 2, 0, "B");
  menu.add(0, 3, 0, "C");
  return true;
}
```

On Android 2.3 and older (2.2, 2.1) is everything fine. But when I run this app on Android 4.0 (ICS - emulator, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S) when I press menu button the app crashdown with this exception:

```
W/ResourceType(9263): Failure getting entry for 0x01090044 (t=8 e=68) in package 0 (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime(9263): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(9263): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a4a1f8)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1090044
E/AndroidRuntime(9263):
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1019)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:70)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$PanelFeatureState.getIconMenuView(PhoneWindow.java:3298)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.initializePanelContent(PhoneWindow.java:1096)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:559)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:817)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1486)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1813)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3273)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I can't localize resource with ID #0x1090044 (it's not in my R.java or any other files) and I don't know what it should be. Maybe some internal menu layout? I already also tried to clean the project.
I know that there are new "desing rules" for Android 4.0 ICS and using Action Bar instead older menu, but I need this code get working even on ICS for many different reasons. Should I some how edit this code to work even on ICS?
I also already tried creating menu from XML file using this code with same exception.

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/Menus) creates an options menu from `menu.add()`, and it works fine on ICS.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to create options menu and I'm pretty sure that it work on ICS. But in my case and in my current project have this kind of error and don't know what do with it.

Comment: The reason I pointed you to a working sample project is that so you can start comparing what you are doing against what the working sample project does, until you find where things are going wrong.

Comment: For anyone else having this problem, it is also happening to me: the only devices it appears on are devices running Android 4.0.3. The error is in `getMenuView` and there is currently no way to intercept it and stop it. In my case I'm simply removing the use of options menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! The problem was in something slightly different. I was using this code:

```
Resources standardResources = getResources();
AssetManager assets = standardResources.getAssets();
DisplayMetrics metrics = standardResources.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
// CORRECT is: Configuration config = standardResources.getConfiguration();
config.locale = new Locale(lang);
Resources defaultResources = new Resources(assets, metrics, config);
```

I didn't check this wrong line of code before because on 2.3 and less everything was fine. But now on 4.0 something was changed in internal resources. I don't know if it is some sort of bug (I'm calling this code for many times in my Activity but only when I use Options menu error is raised), but for sure there was the bug in my code.

Comment: Not convinced this was your bug :). I have the same issue, however nothing as your example above. Filed a bug here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28807 - maybe they can check one level deeper.

Comment: I have similar locale code to that listed above and can confirm I also experience crashes in ICS but my code is slightly different because it is in the Application class; the result is constant calling of onCreate methods.

Comment: There is not enough room here so I have added an answer below with details of why changing Locale causes the error and how to prevent it...

Comment: I had this code in my Activity superclass in onCreate method. Just to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean project and run again. If error isn't gone, check what's the id value in R.java for your menu (R.menu.menu) or if it exists.

Comment: I cleaned and built project many times, but the missing resource ID 0x1090044 is not here. Menu (R.menu.menu) exists and have different ID.

Comment: It sounds like an issue of ICS itself. I suspect the missing resource id is com.android.internal.R.layout.list_menu_item_layout .

Answer (score 0):

According to your Answer the code to manually change locale causes the error but looking at your stack trace it seems that you may have a resource missing, but anyway I have similar Locale change code and was experiencing errors only under ICS so I have added the following in the hope that it may be helpful:

To prevent the error add the following to AndroidManifest.xml
        android:configChanges="locale"

Here is an extract from Activity Javadoc that explains why the error may occur:

> In some special cases, you may want to bypass restarting of your
>   activity based on one or more types of configuration changes.  This is
>   done with the android:configChanges   attribute in its manifest.  For
>   any types of configuration changes you say   that you handle there,
>   you will receive a call to your current activity's
>   onConfigurationChanged method instead of being restarted.  If   a configuration change involves any that you do not handle, however, the
>   activity will still be restarted and onConfigurationChanged
>   will not be called.

Comment: I already had this configChanges atribute set to locale, so it wasn't my problem. But someone maybe can have similar problem.