# Resource not found - Menu - Honeycomb

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am inflating same menu in all the Activities, this is working pretty good in all the activities and devices.
Recently I upgraded Google nexus to honey comb, now, I am facing a weird error - Menu is getting opened in all the activities, other than one Activity.
Its resulting in Resource Not Found.

- No change in the activities.
- Same menu across different activities , why is that resulting in wrong path at only one activity.

DDMS:

```
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1090045
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1018)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2105)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:70)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$PanelFeatureState.getIconMenuView(PhoneWindow.java:3320)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.initializePanelContent(PhoneWindow.java:1096)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.openPanel(PhoneWindow.java:559)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUpPanel(PhoneWindow.java:817)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyUp(PhoneWindow.java:1486)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1813)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3327)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-19 16:03:46.250: E/AndroidRuntime(4269):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 16:03:46.257: W/ActivityManager(134):   Force finishing activity com.supervalu.mobile.android/.CoupanViewActivity
04-19 16:03:46.781: W/ActivityManager(134): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41791d08 com.supervalu.mobile.android/.CoupanViewActivity}
```

---

After a dig at resource id - I found that is not at all declared and removed it.
Even then it is showing error at same resource id but now that resource id is pointing to other view.

Comment: Perhaps, stacktrace and code would shed light on your problem

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project, via Project > Clean in Eclipse or `ant clean` from the command line.

Also, since "honey comb" is not available for any device that could be called "Google nexus", do not be surprised if you have further problems.

Comment: I kept cleaning it countless times, but no use of it :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it was driving me mad. Found the solution now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10251279/454667

Turns out that this line caused the problem:

```
new Resources(mgr, mMetrics, null);
```

where the last param was set to null. Even though this line is in a completely different place.